# Conversion of Excel file with empty sheet fails in print2flash API

Tags: c#, .net

I am using *print2flash* API to convert an excel document to a flash file.

Conversion of Excel file with empty sheet fails. The problem is in setting `batchProcessing`.

```
IBatchProcessingOptions batchProcessing = p2fServer.DefaultBatchProcessingOptions;
batchProcessing.ExcelOptions.SkipEmptySheets = true;
batchProcessing.ApplyChanges();
p2fServer.ConvertFile(inputPath, outputPath, settingProfile, batchProcessing, null);
```

if I don't pass `batchProcessing`, then I won't get the failure.

Error is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Before printing timeout
>   expired at Print2Flash3.IServer.ConvertFile(String SourceFileName,
>   String OutputFileName, Object Profile, Object BatchProcessingOptions,
>   Object PrintingPreferences)

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question on forum of "print2flash". Here is some useful conversation.

http://print2flash.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4772